# Data comparing with sql in Node with express

Tags: sql, node.js

This is my first post here on Stackoverflow. I started programming a while ago and now I'm making my first Node.js application. The login form doesn't work well though. I want to compare the data from the post request with data in the database to see if there is a match. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            var data = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    var user = data[0],
        pass = data[1];

    connection.query('SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [user], [pass], function(err, results) {
        if(results) {
        req.session.regenerate(function() {
            req.session.login = true;
            req.session.username = req.body.username;
            res.redirect('/users/index');
            });
        } else {
              res.render('/');
            }
    });
});
});
```

The modules I'm using are:

```
"ejs": "^2.3.4",
"express": "~4.9.0",
"express-myconnection": "^1.0.4",
"multer": "^1.1.0",
"mysql": "^2.9.0",
"express-session": "~1.9.3"
```

I hope someone can help me get further because I'm stuck for a while now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may want to explain what you mean by "doesn't work well". What you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?

Comment: I get an error: this._callback.apply is not a function. I want to check if the username and password that were filled in to the form are also in the database. If so, I want to start a session for that user (logged in). 

I've looked on the internet for answers and tried some variations but I think the Query isn't correct.

Comment: The error suggests that the code expected a function somewhere and got something else (a function responds to `apply`).  Sure enough, it would appear that `connection.query` takes 3 arguments, the SQL, the values, and the callback.  You're passing 4.  It's likely your user and password values need to be in one array.  (Side note, storing plaintext passwords is bad).

Comment: adding to what @numbers1311407 said, you're passing too many arguments as the query. Try this: ..`[user, pass]`..

Comment: @AshleyB (or @numbers1311407), you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I've written what's in the comments into an answer as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that connection.query (of the mysql npm module) accepts 3 parameters -

- The query
- An Array of values to be escaped
- The callback function

You've tried to use 4 parameters. The following should work:

`connection.query('SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [user, pass], function(err, results) { ...`

Comment: No problem, can you accept my answer as the solution if you've found it to be useful? (click the tick icon near my question). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry didn't see your response, I've accepted your answer =)